# How To Configure Asp.net 3.5 to use excel interop

Tags: asp.net

How can I configure my asp.net application to work with excel interop. I added a reference to my application but when I try and say Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel it doesnt work. I must be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems eventhough intellisense doesnt work initially when I build the app it compiles and works.